# error after committing code in git (jsp+servlets)

Tags: java, git, jsp, servlets

I have a java web project (jsp + servlets) that the local code works the property registry, if I commit to git and then give a git pull or git clone the property registry stops working, but none appear error, it simply does not record the data and only returns to the success page, this problem only occurs when I try to commit this version.

I tried to create a new repository and upload it as a new project but the problem continues

this is the DAO class

```
public boolean cadastrar(Imovel imovel) throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConexao();

        //Endereço
        String INSERTIMOVEL = "INSERT INTO Imovel VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        String INSERTENDERECO = "INSERT INTO Endereco VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        smt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERTENDERECO, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        smt.setString(1, imovel.getEndereco().getLogradouro());
        smt.setString(2, imovel.getEndereco().getComplemento());
        smt.setInt(3, imovel.getEndereco().getNumero());
        smt.setString(4, imovel.getEndereco().getCidade());
        smt.setString(5, imovel.getEndereco().getCep());
        smt.setString(6, imovel.getEndereco().getBairro());
        smt.setString(7, imovel.getEndereco().getEstado());
        smt.execute();

        rs = smt.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();

        //imovel
        smt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERTIMOVEL);
        smt.setString(1, imovel.getTitulo());
        smt.setString(2, imovel.getDescricao());
        smt.setString(3, "Em Análise");
        smt.setString(4, "Ativo");
        smt.setDouble(5, imovel.getValor());
        smt.setDouble(6, imovel.getArea_total());
        smt.setDouble(7, imovel.getArea_edificada());
        smt.setInt(8, imovel.getComodos());
        smt.setInt(9, imovel.getVagas_garagem());
        smt.setInt(10, imovel.getBanheiros());
        smt.setTimestamp(11, timestamp);
        smt.setString(12, imovel.getDiretorio_imagem());
        smt.setString(13, imovel.getTipo_imovel());
        smt.setInt(14, imovel.getUsuario().getId_usuario());
        smt.setInt(15, rs.getInt(1));
        boolean rowInserted = smt.executeUpdate() > 0;

        rs.close();
        smt.close();
        connection.close();
        return rowInserted;
    }
```

and this is the controller (i use command and factory patterns)

```
@Override
    public String executar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {

            HttpSession usuarioLogado = request.getSession();
            Sessao sessao = (Sessao) usuarioLogado.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");

            Part filePart = request.getPart("uploadFile"); // 
            String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); //
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

            imovel.setDiretorio_imagem(sessao.getId_usuario() + File.separator + fileName);

            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = fileContent.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();

            // cria o diretorio de upload
            // esse caminho e relativo ao diretorio da aplicacao
            ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
            String uploadPath = context.getRealPath("/") + "Resources\\upload" + File.separator + sessao.getId_usuario();

            // caso o diretorio nao exista o bloco abaixo cria o mesmo
            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
            if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            //converte o array de bytes em file e grava no diretorio
            File f = new File(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName);
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                fos.write(bytes);
            }

            //Imovel Requests
            String titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
            String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");
            int comodos = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("comodos"));
            int banheiro = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("banheiro"));
            int garagem = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("garagem"));
            Double valor = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valorimovel"));
            Double areatotal = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("areatotal"));
            Double areaedificada = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("areaedificada"));
            String tpimovel = request.getParameter("tpimovel");

            imovel.setTitulo(titulo);
            imovel.setDescricao(descricao);
            imovel.setComodos(comodos);
            imovel.setBanheiros(banheiro);
            imovel.setVagas_garagem(garagem);
            imovel.setValor(valor);
            imovel.setArea_total(areatotal);
            imovel.setArea_edificada(areaedificada);
            imovel.setTipo_imovel(tpimovel);
            imovel.getUsuario().setId_usuario(sessao.getId_usuario());

            //Endereço Requests
            String logradouro = request.getParameter("logradouro");
            int numero = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));
            String complemento = request.getParameter("complemento");
            String cidade = request.getParameter("cidade");
            String estado = request.getParameter("estado");
            String cep = request.getParameter("cep");
            String bairro = request.getParameter("bairro");

            //Endereço Set's
            imovel.getEndereco().setLogradouro(logradouro);
            imovel.getEndereco().setNumero(numero);
            imovel.getEndereco().setComplemento(complemento);
            imovel.getEndereco().setCidade(cidade);
            imovel.getEndereco().setEstado(estado);
            imovel.getEndereco().setCep(cep);
            imovel.getEndereco().setBairro(bairro);

            ImovelDAO dao = new ImovelDAO();

            if (dao.cadastrar(imovel)) {
                request.setAttribute("msg", "Seu imóvel foi cadastrado e passará por uma análise, fique de olho no seu email!");
                return "index.jsp";
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("msgerro", "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar cadastrar o imóvel, tente novamente");
                return "index.jsp";
            }
        } catch (SQLException | NumberFormatException | IOException | ServletException | MessagingException ex) {
            request.setAttribute("msgerro", ex.getMessage());
            return "index.jsp";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `smt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERTIMOVEL);` closes the previous `statement` **and** `ResultSet`. Get the value before that line.

```
int val = rs.getInt(1);
smt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERTIMOVEL);
// ...
smt.setInt(15, val);
```

If that is not the issue, please edit your question to include any exceptions or a diff with the last working version.

Comment: there's no difference between last commit and this, the local code works the issue only occurs when i a commit and use git pull or git clone

Comment: If there's no difference, then what are you committing to git?

Comment: I managed to solve, in the code in the register the command uploadDir.mkdir() was wrong for my case (i need to create more than one folder), the correct one is uploadDir.mkdirs(); to create the cascading folders. The local commit works because folder already exists in the project, but when i clone the folder doens't exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about statement and ResultSet.

Comment: when I said there was no difference I was referring to the codes mentioned here that were in error, but there were other changes